# Laravel add function to model

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, laravel, model, eloquent

I want to add a function to a Laravel model like I'm used to in Rails.

For example:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    def name
        "#{firstname} #{lastname}"
    end
end
```

When I try to use the same approach in Laravel I get the following exception:

```
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
```

How do I get this behaviour in Laravel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an Accessor in your model using a method name of getXXXAttribute:

```
class Person extends Eloquent {

    public function getNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value->firstname . ' ' . $value->lastname;
    }

}
```

And you can then reference it in your model using

```
$person->name
```

Watch out for snake case/camel case differences if you want to use names like full_name: use camel case in the method name

```
class Person extends Eloquent {

    public function getFullNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value->firstname . ' ' . $value->lastname;
    }

}
```

but snake case when you need to access it

```
$person->full_name
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Where can I find documentation for this? I've tried searching online for a while but couldn't find anything.

Comment: [Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) It doesn't particularly reference or show examples of creating new attributes, simply modifying existing ones, but its still perfectly acceptable to do so